# Why cannot Kotlin infer the following lambda argument (after Java -> Kotlin conversion)?

Tags: java, android, lambda, kotlin

I had the following Java code:

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    public interface Predicate<T> {
        boolean test(T t);
    }

    private interface Consumer<T> {
        void apply(T t);
    }

    private void updateLiveLists() {
        updateLiveLists(liveList -> true);
    }

    private void updateLiveLists(Predicate<MutableLiveList<?>> predicate) {
        forEachLiveList(liveList -> {
            if (predicate.test(liveList)) {
                refresh(liveList);
            }
        });
    }

    private void forEachLiveList(Consumer<MutableLiveList<?>> consumer) {
        ...
    }
```

Then I used `Java -> Kotlin conversion` in Android Studio:

```
class DatabaseManager {
    interface Predicate<T> {
        fun test(t: T): Boolean
    }

    private interface Consumer<T> {
        fun apply(t: T)
    }

    private fun updateLiveLists(predicate: Predicate<MutableLiveList<*>> = { liveList -> true }) {
        forEachLiveList({ liveList ->
            if (predicate.test(liveList)) {
                refresh(liveList)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun forEachLiveList(consumer: Consumer<MutableLiveList<*>>) {
       ...
    }
```

Fails with the following error:

> Type mismatch
>
> `Required: DatabaseManager.Consumer<MutableLiveList<*>>`
>
> Found: (???) -> Unit

Now I had to change code to following:

```
private fun updateLiveLists(predicate: Predicate<MutableLiveList<*>> = object : Predicate<MutableLiveList<*>> {
    override fun test(t: MutableLiveList<*>): Boolean {
        return true;
    }
}) {
    forEachLiveList(object : DatabaseManager.Consumer<MutableLiveList<*>> { // <--- !!
        override fun apply(t: MutableLiveList<*>) {
            if (predicate.test(t)) {
                refresh(t)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Okay, so I had to explicitly declare this anonymous interface as an explicit subclass of `object`, as for whatever reason Kotlin couldn't figure out the lambda.**

---

If it helps, I have the same problem occurring in a function below it:

```
fun refresh(vararg tables: Table) {
    updateLiveLists({ liveList ->
        for (table in tables) {
            if (liveList.getTable() === table) {
                return@updateLiveLists true
            }
        }
        false
    })
}
```

Which says:

> Type Mismatch:
>
> `Required: DatabaseManager.Predicate<MutableLiveList<*>>`
>
> Found: ??? -> Boolean

And I have to do this instead

```
fun refresh(vararg tables: Table) {
    updateLiveLists(object: DatabaseManager.Predicate<MutableLiveList<*>> { // <--
        override fun test(t: MutableLiveList<*>): Boolean {
            for (table in tables) {
                if (t.getTable() === table) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

**Why, and how can I avoid this? How can I use my own Predicate/Consumer without Kotlin getting confused about the lambda type?**

Comment: It's the most shortest question as I seen today)

Comment: I think here you can find answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235423/converted-java-class-file-to-kotlin-makes-compilation-error

Comment: @DimaKozhevin it is kinda long because I posted 2 examples in which the failure occurs.

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili so it says I either need to use `object :` as I did above, or change these interfaces to `typealias` of Kotlin's function types, or use Kotlin's function types directly? Changing to `typealias` or to Kotlin types would work only if I change all code that uses this to Kotlin as well. Hrmm... Yes, that **is** a very relevant question.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, or you could leave functional interfaces in Java and implement them in Kotlin. At least this I think is hinted at in linked answer.

Comment: yep, you have a two options if you convert your code to Kotlin, in my case I preferred typealiases

Comment: see also [SAM Conversion on Kotlin Interfaces](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/sam-conversion-on-kotlin-interfaces/1433) - good discussion

Comment: The **Converter** has a bug.  I.e., having found a lambda in the original Java source code, and having converted the original java interface to a Kotlin interface, the converter should have also converted the lambda to a compatible type - IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `/u/lupajz` I now know that the problem is that interfaces defined in Kotlin are **not** converted by the SAM conversion because of https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-and-sam-interface-with-two-parameters/293/5

Basically it boils down to

> "why would you do it this way when you can use Kotlin's functional interfaces and type-aliases instead; if you need this then define the interfaces in Java".

---

There are a few workarounds:

1.) inline objects (which is what I showed above as part of the question)

2.) type aliases + exposing overloaded methods

```
private typealias KotlinPredicate<T> = (T) -> Boolean;

private typealias KotlinConsumer<T> = (T) -> Unit;

class DatabaseManager {
    private interface Consumer<T> {
        fun apply(t : T) : Unit;
    }

    private fun forEachLiveList(consumer: Consumer<MutableLiveList<*>>) {
        forEachLiveList({
            consumer.apply(it)
        })
    }

    private fun forEachLiveList(consumer: KotlinConsumer<MutableLiveList<*>>) {
        ...
    }
```

and

```
interface Predicate<T> {
    fun test(t : T) : Boolean;
}


fun updateLiveLists(predicate: Predicate<MutableLiveList<*>>) {
    updateLiveLists({
        predicate.test(it)
    })
}

fun updateLiveLists(predicate: KotlinPredicate<MutableLiveList<*>> = { liveList -> true }) {
    forEachLiveList({ liveList ->
        if (predicate.invoke(liveList)) {
            refresh(liveList)
        }
    })
}
```